# using jaxws binding with required=false

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, xjc, jaxws-maven-plugin

We have a bunch of .wsdl files and have defined an execution goal for each one of them, each with their own bindings file. That makes 71 execution goals and 71 bindings files with mostly the same content. However the reason why a lot of bindings files are needed is because they use `<jaxws:bindings node="xyz">` where `xyz` is not necessarily present in the other .wsdl files and then xjc throws an error that `XPath evaluation results in empty target node`.

I've tried with `<jaxws:bindings node="xyz" required="false">` but apparently that only works for `jxb:bindings` and not for jaxws:bindings.

I'm trying to reduce the 71 bindings file to hopefully 1 with a lot of optional statements.

I've tried with different maven plugins: Apache's wsdl2java, jaxws-mvn-plugin and I think one more, but I doubt that makes a difference since in the back they all use xjc.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

I tried `required="false"`, and was expecting it to work for jaxws:bindings the same way it does for jaxb:bindings, which it doesn't.